# Scrolling Background Image within <div>

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a background image within a div scroll with my text.
Right now the image simply stays at the top of the page as I scroll down. 
Below is what I have written on the actual page followed by two classes on my stylesheet. The latter of the two is simply a placeholder that I keep fooling around with. Been through probably 100 links in the past few hours and still cannot get to the bottom of this.

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="gunbg"></div>
</div>

.main 
{
    position: fixed;
    left:178px; top:155px; right:0; bottom:0;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.main .bgmain
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url('images/gunbg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to do parallax effect?

Comment: [**background-attachment property**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

Comment: freestock.tk I have been to this page and I must be doing something wrong because I cannot get that to work. I either need to the image to span the whole page and the text moves up and down freely. Or I need the image to move as I scroll. I'm guessing both are doable, I'm just very new to html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to fix your css

HTML

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="gunbg">
          <h1>
          Hello World
          </h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  background: url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_559332799_Tree_Rings.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 130vh;
}


.gunbg{
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:200px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/3k959rnp/)

Comment: Fiido, thanks a million. This is exactly what I have been trying accomplish.

Comment: Don't mention it mate. Just sharing the knowledge. Enjoy your day.

Comment: I tried, but my rep isn't high enough. Sorry my friend.

Comment: Hey, another quick question if you find the time. If I wanted to adjust the opacity of just the background image what would be the easiest way?